# Efficient way to find positions of one-letter words

Tags: r, regex

Let's have a vector of strings:

```
s <- c("GATTTT,A,T,GATTCTATTCT,GATTCTATTCTATTCT", "ATTCTATTCTC", "G")
```

I want to find positions of the one-letter words in each string, so the expected result would be:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

My solution fails to provide the intended result:

```
sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", s), FUN = function(x) which(diff(x) == 2))
```

I need a solution in R that will be time- and memory-efficient for very long character vectors and would be able to find one-letter words in strings with a variable number of words. The delimiter is always a comma, if that helps.

Comment: For `Single Letter word` you can uselike this `sapply(strsplit(s, ","), function(words) which(nchar(words) == 1))`

Comment: There are many ways to extract single character strings in R.  Solutions have already been suggested in comments and answers.  But you ask about efficiency.  The optimal answers therefore depends on what you mean by "efficient": fastest execution time? minimum code length?  maximum generalisability?  Whatever your criterion, the best answer may depend on the structure and size of your data.  I don't think you've provided enough information for us to be certain what the most efficient solution is, though you will get many offers of solutions that work.

Comment: @Limey I'm looking for fast execution time and low memory requirements. The question is now edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use `gregexpr`:

```
lapply(gregexpr("[^,]+", s), \(x) {
  . <- which(attr(x, "match.length")==1); if(length(.)>0) . else NA})
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] NA
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1
```

or `strsplit`:

```
lapply(strsplit(s, ",", fixed=TRUE), \(x) {
  . <- which(nchar(x) == 1); if(length(.)>0) . else NA})
```

or in 2 steps to replace with `NA`:

```
. <- lapply(strsplit(s, ",", fixed=TRUE), \(x) which(nchar(x) == 1))
.[lengths(.)==0] <- NA
```

or

```
Map(\(x, y) if(y==1) 1 else {. <- which(diff(c(0, x, y+1)) == 2)
  if(length(.)>0) . else NA}, gregexpr(",", s, fixed=TRUE), nchar(s))
```

Looking what is faster and uses low memory with the provided dataset.

```
bench::mark(
"gregexpr" = lapply(gregexpr("[^,]+", s), \(x) {. <- which(attr(x, "match.length")==1); if(length(.)>0) . else NA}),
"strsplit" = lapply(strsplit(s, ",", fixed=TRUE), \(x) {. <- which(nchar(x) == 1); if(length(.)>0) . else NA}),
"2step" = {. <- lapply(strsplit(s, ",", fixed=TRUE), \(x) which(nchar(x) == 1))
.[lengths(.)==0] <- NA
.},
"Map" = Map(\(x, y) if(y==1) 1 else {. <- which(diff(c(0, x, y+1)) == 2)
  if(length(.)>0) . else NA}, gregexpr(",", s, fixed=TRUE), nchar(s))
)
#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 gregexpr     26.1µs  28.2µs  34180. 45.73KB    13.7  9996     4   292ms <list>
#2 strsplit     17.6µs    19µs  51634. 21.77KB    15.5  9997     3   194ms <list>
#3 2step        19.6µs  21.2µs  46018.  9.49KB    13.8  9997     3   217ms <list>
#4 Map          42.8µs    45µs  21684. 56.34KB    13.0  9994     6   461ms <list>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Can you explain what the `.` and `\(x)` mean?

Comment: `.` is just a variable (used by me typical for temporal storage). `\(x)` is a shorthand for `function(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

With `strsplit`:

```r
sapply(strsplit(s, ",", fixed = TRUE), FUN = function(x) which(nchar(x) == 1))
```

```r
[[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

---

To get NAs instead of empty vectors (although probably not very efficient:

```r
sapply(strsplit(s, ",", fixed = TRUE), FUN = function(x) if(all(nchar(x) != 1)) NA else which(nchar(x) == 1))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can this be modified to replace integer(0) with NA?

Comment: `fixed = TRUE` in `strsplit()` would make it substantially faster.

Comment: Right, added to the asnwer: )